# facebook api for reflecting events

Tags: facebook, erlang

I want to develop a carrom game.
I don't want to integrate this game in facebook. but when one of the players playing the game the others must able to see that changes on their own computer.

This can be done via facebook(means players must log in to facebook). So is there any facebook_erlang api to send events to other players?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Facebook API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/) you can build an application. Doesn't have to be Erlang. If you want to build an application where players can send messages you can do that within your Facebook application, which can be build using Erlang.